# Does the amplitude have an affect on the frequency in longitudinal waves?

Tags: waves

I was wondering about how the amplitude of a longitudinal wave would be like and searched for it and found this definition:

> **Amplitude**
>   The **amplitude** is the maximum displacement from equilibrium. For a longitudinal wave which is a pressure wave this would be the maximum increase (or decrease) in pressure from the equilibrium pressure that is cause when a compression (or rarefaction) passes a point.

So I understood that the amplitude affects the frequency and reduces it because with higher amplitudes the particles are going to be pushed further so the successive compressions will have a bigger distance between them.

Is this right?

Comment: It depends on the wave

Comment: I don't understand and I think what is the difference now between the wave length and the amplitude of  a longitudinal wave ?